# Libre Office Writer: assign shortcut to bookmark

Tags: macros, shortcuts, bookmarks, libreoffice-writer, navigation

In this large file I have a few bookmarks which I go to quite a lot.

I simply want to assign a shortcut (hotkey) to one of them.

I couldn't see any way to "directly" assign a hotkey (e.g. Ctrl-Shift-B) to a given bookmark, e.g. by right-clicking the bookmark in the "Navigator" dialog.

So I thought: OK, presumably if I record a macro I can then "customise" the macro to do this (NB Security settings are set so I can create macros...).

So I recorded such a macro.  When I run the macro nothing happens.  I tried it two ways: one by bringing up the Navigator dialog, another by going *Insert -> Bookmark -> (select Bookmark) --> Go to bookmark*.  Neither worked.  The macro code seems to "give up" when you open one of these dialogs (i.e. cannot then automate/emulate user actions taken in these dialogs).

Finally I thought of looking in the commands which are available to customise: *Tools --> Customise --> Keyboard ... Category box: select Navigate* and... I see nothing promising... except possibly "To Reference" ... but assigning a shortcut to this seems to have no effect.

At the moment the best I can do is go F5 and then select my bookmark manually in the Navigator dialog and then press Enter...

Is there not a way of setting things so you can navigate to a bookmark (or for that matter another location of some kind as shown in the Navigator dialog) using just one shortcut?